# Why is prototype assignment not working here?

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
var foo = {
    name: "foo"
};

var bar = {};

bar.prototype = foo;

document.writeln("Bar name: " + bar.name + "<br />");
```

And here's what I got in browser:

`Bar name: undefined`

Why is this happening? Shouldn't Javascript look up name on bar, and then go up on foo and finds it? Why is it simply undefined?

Comment: Unfortunately, in Javascript `x.prototype` != "prototype of x"

Comment: @thg435 Can you explain more about this?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, in Javascript x.prototype != "prototype of x". `x.prototype` means "if `x` is a constructor (=function), `x.prototype` will be a prototype of `new x`". If x is not a function, `x.prototype` doesn't make sense.

This is no more and no less confusing than the rest of the language. Remember, Mr. Eich had only 10 days to create it [[ref](http://www.computer.org/csdl/mags/co/2012/02/mco2012020007.html)].

To assign a prototype to an already created object, ES6 (Harmony) offers [`setPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf). In other engines, there's a vendor-specific hack `o.__proto__=...`. Mostly, it's a bad idea.

Comment: and `var bar = {}` means that `bar` is just an object, not a constructor.

Comment: Then how do I explicitly assign a prototype to an object (not at creation using `Object.create()`)?

Comment: You don't explicitly assign a prototype to an object. You assing it to the constuctor function.

Answer (score 1):

As others already correctly explained, the prototype system doesn't work like that in ECMAscript. You should instead use ECMAscripts [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) method, which will do the magic for you.

```
var foo = {
    name: "foo"
};

var bar = Object.create( foo );

console.log("Bar name: " + bar.name);
```

`.create()` will pretty much do this under the hood:

```
Object.create = (function(){
  function F(){}

  return function( o ){
      F.prototype = o;
      return new F()
  }
})();
```

Comment: +1 for the workaround. `instanceof` is still out of order though :/

Comment: True. But you can go like `foo.isPrototypeOf( bar );`

Comment: Afaik, both were introduced within the "HTML5" standard/spec. So whatever is valid for `Object.create` (on browser support) should be the same for `Object.isPrototypeOf` and `Object.getPrototypeOf` etc.

Answer (score 0):

The `prototype` property, that is used for inheritance in JavaScript, is a member of the constructor function. It is not a member of the object that is created from the constructor function.

The object that is created from the constructor function has an internal property `[[Prototype]]` which is the same as the `prototype` property of the constuctor function. When you access a property on an object and the object does not have that property on its own, the `[[Prototype]]` object is searched for that property. But the `[[Prototype]]` property itself is not accessible from the language (it's only there for specification purposes).

Comment: except that `[[Prototype]]` is made visible in many browsers as `__proto__`.

Comment: `__proto__` is deprecated in Firefox at least.

Comment: deprecated, and non-standard, indeed, but in the meantime it is accessible.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly set the `prototype` property on a plain object.

When you define a (constructor) function you can specify the `prototype` property of that function, and when that constructor is subsequently invoked the given property will be attached to the prototype chain of the new object.

So this would work:

```
var foo = { name: "foo" };

function Bar() { ... }
Bar.prototype = foo;

var b = new Bar();
// b.name now exists
```

However in ES5 you should use `Object.create` instead.