# Using a function in Javascript to Generate Noninstantiated Functions

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I have the following code:

```
function Rune(){
    this.subSpells = [];
}
function Modifier(){
    this.type = "modifier";
}
Modifier.prototype = new Rune();

function RuneFactory(effect, inheritsFrom, initialValue){
    var toReturn = function(){}; 
    toReturn.prototype = new inheritsFrom();
    toReturn.prototype.subSpells[effect] = initialValue;
    return toReturn;
}

Duration = RuneFactory("duration", Modifier, 1);
Quicken = RuneFactory("quicken", Modifier, 1);

x = new Duration();
y = new Quicken();
```

Both x.subSpells.duration and x.subSpells.quicken equal 1. Same with y. 
I want x.subSpells.quicken and y.subSpells.duration to be undefined.

If I do the following for the Duration and Quicken definitions, I get the behaviour I want.

```
Duration = RuneFactory("duration", Rune, 1);
Quicken = RuneFactory("quicken", Rune, 1);
```

I think there is a problem with double inheritance. Can anyone tell me how to change my RuneFactory code such that it works with double inheritance and/or explain what's breaking? If at all possible, I would like to avoid using a framework.

Thank you!

Comment: Add following line in the Modifier function `Rune.apply(this, arguments);`, since `subSpells` defined at prototype level, all instance of Rune refer to same object.

Comment: +1 However, be aware that the `Rune` constructor will be called twice, once to populate the prototype of `Modifier`, and once for the instanciation. You should replace `Modifier.prototype = new Rune()` with `Modifier.prototype = Object.create(Rune.prototype)` to avoid this. Note : `Object.create` is a recent feature, go here for a workaround in old browsers if needed : http://stackoverflow.com/a/20879584/1636522.

Comment: Side note: you are specifying a string index to an array--shouldn't subspells be an object instead?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. In either way, I get a value of `1`. And you are explicitly setting it to `1` with the `initialValue`. So why do you expect it to be `undefined`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: The inheritance looks fine to me - whether you pass in Rune or Modifier to inherit from, the result still has a subSpells property.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Crockford's Prototypal inheritance - Issues with nested objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131052/crockfords-prototypal-inheritance-issues-with-nested-objects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add following line in the Modifier function `Rune.apply(this, arguments);`, since `subSpells` defined at prototype level, all instance of Rune refer to same object.
And, change type of `subSpells` from array to object.

As mentioned by **wared** would be better if you use Parasitic Combination Inheritance Pattern.

"*I think there is a problem with double inheritance*" - No!

At first, there's no such thing as double inheritance, you have same problem as with Modifier constructor, your instances refer to same `subSpells` object (Array in your case. read about [Primitive value vs Reference value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266616/primitive-value-vs-reference-value) or [References and Values](http://yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/references.html) *it's about .NET, but basic principles are the same in programming*).

Look at [How does JavaScript .prototype work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work)

---

Look at [***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/L7dVL/)

```
function inheritPrototype(subType, superType) {
    var prototype = Object.create(superType.prototype, {
        constructor: {
            value: subType,
            enumerable: true
        }
    });

    subType.prototype = prototype;
}

function Rune() {
    this.subSpells = {};
}

function Modifier() {
    Rune.apply(this, arguments);
    this.type = "modifier";
}

inheritPrototype(Modifier, Rune);

function RuneFactory(effect, inheritsFrom, initialValue) {
    function toReturn() {
        inheritsFrom.apply(this, arguments); // you should bind this
        this.subSpells[effect] = initialValue;
    }
    inheritPrototype(toReturn, inheritsFrom);
    return toReturn;
}

Duration = RuneFactory("duration", Modifier, 1);
Quicken = RuneFactory("quicken", Modifier, 1);

x = new Duration();
y = new Quicken();

console.log(x.subSpells.duration); // 1
console.log(x.subSpells.quicken); // undefined

console.log(y.subSpells.duration); // undefined
console.log(y.subSpells.quicken); // 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to inherit in JavaScript is:

```
function Parent(arg1, arg2) {
    // Do something
}

function Child(arg1, arg2) {
    Parent.call(this, arg1, arg2); // or Parent.apply(this, arguments)
}

Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype, {
    constructor: {
        value: Child
    }
});
```

So you will need something like this:

```
function Rune(){
    this.subSpells = {};
}

function Modifier(){
    Rune.apply(this, arguments);
    this.type = "modifier";
}

Modifier.prototype = Object.create(Rune.prototype, {
    constructor: {
        value: Modifier
    }
});

function RuneFactory(effect, inheritsFrom, initialValue){
    var toReturn = function(){}; 
    toReturn.prototype = Object.create(inheritsFrom.prototype, {
        constructor: {
            value: Modifier
        }
    });
    toReturn.prototype.subSpells = {};
    toReturn.prototype.subSpells[effect] = initialValue;
    return toReturn;
}

Duration = RuneFactory("duration", Modifier, 1);
Quicken = RuneFactory("quicken", Modifier, 1);

x = new Duration();
y = new Quicken();
```

NOTE: in your question `.subSpells` is an array but you assign an member as it would be an object!